# errors in youtube javascript api

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am getting few errors while playing video using YouTube Player Tools - Iframe API.I am getting these 6 errors in the console window of my browser

> 1.Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ( 'https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://127.0.0.1').
>   2.GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
>   
> 3.GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
>   
> 4.GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
>   
> 5.GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
>   
> 6.GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED

my index.php is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id='player'></div>
<!--iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe-->

  <script>

      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '500',
          width: '500',
          videoId: 'wbLBHYAd0kE',//videos[currentid],
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 10000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
          alert();
        player.stopVideo();
      }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to do to remove these errors?

Answer (score 0):

**1st error:**

turn

```
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

into

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

**for errors 2-6:** This is a known bug with the official Chromecast JavaScript library. Instead of failing silently, it dumps these error messages in all non-Chrome browsers as well as Chrome browsers where the Chromecast extension isn't present.